# How to control output voltage of DC to DC Step Up Fly Back?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback, step-up, isolated

I need to control the output voltage of  **Isolated Flyback Step-Up** power supply using an MCU may be using DAC or PWM or via a digital pot,
how to do this?

**spec** 
Vin 5V - 8V

Iout 40mA

Vout max 100V
Vout control range 0V-100V or 5V-100V

I am using ti power bench to design the flyback isolated converter
I don't know how to control the output voltage of it

Comment: You're probably going to have a hard time getting such a wide output range from a conventional flyback.  You can move the output voltage by injecting current into the feedback node with a DAC for example, but getting a 20:1 range will probably be difficult.

Comment: i did not get  **but getting a 20:1 range will probably be difficult** what is 20:1

Comment: 5 volt to 100 volt as per your question is a 20:1 control range.